# Android USB-Debugging: Device recognized but then loses connection

Tags: android, debugging, connection, usb

I followed the steps for USB Debugging showed [here under paragraph 8](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-an-android-app-build-environment-with-eclipse-android-sdk-phonegap-debian-squeeze-p5) and my HTC Desire is recognized once:`./adb devices
List of devices attached

SH0BJPL02419    device`

Then I run the exact same command once more and the connection is lost. Sometimes I can also see the devices three times but after a couple of secs the connection is gone.

USB Debugging is still displayed as 'on' on the phone, though.

I use Debian Squeeze 64bit.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: First off - I don't really know.
Secondly - perhaps trying the same process on another kernel/OS may help you verify that it's an OS/config issue and not something on the phone itself..? Just a thought, maybe helpful maybe not..

Comment: It surprised me by working constantly all of a sudden, can't give you hints why.

Comment: ... and lost it again. It hasn't been working constantly after numerous attempts of killing and restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting 'harddrive' on the phone did the trick in case anyone is interested.